# How to unset a item in Yii session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, yii, unset

**My Session Array**

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
$session['product']=array(0=>array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Cocacola'),1=>array('id'=>'2','name'=>'Pepsi'));

print_r($session['cart']);
//output is
//Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Cocacola ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Pepsi ) )
```

**Now i want to unset one product from my array**

```
unset($session['cart'][0]);//unset Cocacola Product

print_r($session['cart']);
//output is
//Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Cocacola ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Pepsi ) )
```

***But both output is same. unset() not working. Please help me sort it out. 
Thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your $session

```
$session['product']=array(0=>array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Cocacola'),1=>array('id'=>'2','name'=>'Pepsi'));
```

Try like this ,   use $temp array

```
$temp = $session['product'];
unset($temp[0]);
$session['product'] = $temp;
```